# Sliding a breadcrumb off the left of the page with JQuery/CSS

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am working on the mobile view of an app that has a breadcrumb that needs to start at the left of the screen and then, as breadcrumbs get added, push the current ones to the left and then, eventually, off the screen. If the person moves back on the app, the current one gets removed.

I have it where it works but the crumbs start to the right (where the furthest it can go is.

```js
function update_crumbs(){
  $('.crumbs').empty();
  $.each(crumbs,function(key,value){

    if(value!==''){
      let is_active = (key + 1 === crumbs.length) ? 'active' : '';
      $('.crumbs').append(' <span class="connector ' + is_active+ '"></span><span class="crumb ' + is_active+ '" data-index="0"> '+ value +'</span>');
    }
  })
}
```

```css
.crumbs-container {
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
  position: relative;
  height: 80px;
}
.crumbs-container .crumbs {
  margin: 20px 0;
  padding: 13px 0;
  position: absolute;
  right: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="crumbs-container">
  <div class="crumbs"> 
    <span class="crumb active" data-index="0"> Appointment</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

And then the JS just adds/appends a crumb as the person moves further forward. Thanks and let me know if you can see what i am doing wrong or how to modify it so it work start towards the left and push when it reaches the right of the screen.

Comment: Can you provide your js code ?

Comment: Added the JS to the post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for your suggestions. I ended up using JQuery to determine the size of the screen and then the size of the breadcrumb container. Id the container was larger than the screen size, I added a negative margin to the left, taking the difference if the screen size and the container and adding padding to move it off the right side of the screen.

```
    //If the breadcrumbs exceed the width of the screen, move them to the left
          if($('.crumbs').width() > $(window).width()){
            let offset = -Math.abs(($('.crumbs').width() - $(window).width()) + 40);
            $('.crumbs').css('margin-left',offset)
          }else{
            $('.crumbs').css('margin-left','')
}
```

Hope this can help someone else.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add left position for crumbs instead of right as 0px

```
.crumbs-container .crumbs {
     right: auto;
     left: 0;
}

.crumbs-container {
    white-space: normal;
}
```

Comment: Adding that CSS does position the crumbs to the left but then they fall off the screen to the right. I need them to hit the right side and then push the items to the left off the screen. Thanks!

Comment: I may have missed something but by adding white-space:normal, the breadcrumbs now fall to a second line and not push the ones to the left out of frame.